# Webm Autoplay Doesn't Play

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to show an video on homepage. I know that ios and android don't allow to play video automatically but I see some websites can do that. My question is, how can we make this? Any idea?

```
<video playsinline autoplay loop muted style="min-width:100%; min-height:100%;" >
    <source type="video/webm" src="//bg.cdn.ustudio.com/app/transcodes/TuX1xml2yZsS.webm">
</video>
```

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't autoplay because the url doesn't return a .webm video. Try it with https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm

Comment: @obscure No, I tried with my own webm file. The code is just an example

Answer (score 0):

`but I see some websites can do that` You likely see that in chrome?

Some sites can auto play if they have crossed the [Media Engagement Index](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#mei) This happens if a person has visited a site many times and played videos, Chrome assumes the user wants to see videos on that site, and allows autoplay. Its not something you can force for the user.

Comment: No, I see that in Safari. For example nike.com can do that